# Calling variables from other class

Tags: java, multithreading, variables

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ThreadClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the characters, Press Enter to begin");
        System.out.println("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String scr= sc.nextLine();

        MyThread tr=new MyThread();
        try {
            tr.sleep(11000);
            System.out.println("Time Over");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


}



public class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Time over");
        ThreadClass tc=new ThreadClass();
        String str=tc.scr;
        if(str.equals("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
        {
        System.out.println("Successfully completed");
    }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The typed Words do not match");
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to make an application that prompts the user to type a string within 11 seconds. To accomplish this I have two classes namely ThreadClass and MyThread. In Thread class I have defined methods to take input from the user and to set the timer to 10 seconds. In MyThread class I have defined methods for post thread completion i.e. what the program will do after the time is over. I want to add a feature in MyThread class so that it compares the user input with the string provided. The problem is that when I try to access the String variable scr, defined in ThreadClass from MyThread class by creating an it gives me an error. Even if I try to extend ThreadClass from MyThread class it gives me an error. Also declaring scr as static gives me the same result. Is there any possible way to use scr variable in MyThread?

Comment: Just saying "it gives me an error" does not give us very much information about your problem.  You will be more likely to get quality answers to you question if you include the text of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had while ago same issue, i used Concurrency API from java, and it works without problem
here is solution for your problem

```
public class ThreadClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

            Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {

                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    System.out
                            .println("Enter the characters, Press Enter to begin");
                    System.out
                            .println("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    return sc.nextLine();
                }
            });
            try {
                String str = future.get(11, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("Your string " + str);
            } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                future.cancel(true);
                System.out.println("Time Over");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what the error message is, but I can guess.

```
ThreadClass tc=new ThreadClass();
String str=tc.scr;
```

There is no instance variable named `scr` in your `ThreadClass` class.  There is only a *local variable* with that name in your `main()` routine.

If you do not yet understand the difference between local variables, instance variables (a.k.a., "fields") and class variables (a.k.a., "static variables"), then it might be a little bit early for you to be trying to understand threads.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know how can I declare a local variable in another class.

Comment: @PratikPaul I don't understand what you mean by "declare a local variable in another class."  First of all, I don't normally think of local variables being declared in a class.  Even though it's technically true, it's not a useful way to think about them.  What matters is that local variables are declared in _methods_.  Second of all, "declare a variable in _another_ class?" Variables are declared in the classes that they are declared in.  My best guess is that maybe the word "declare" means something different to you.